# EIEIO: raise an error if a method is called when a particular slot's value is nil

Tags: eieio, classes

I have an EIEIO class with a variety of methods. I now want a select subset of these methods to raise an error if they are called while an instance's `is_open` slot is set to `nil`. How would you approach this? My initial idea was to make a macro to safely call this class' methods, e.g. `(safe_call class_instance method arg1 arg2 ...)`, but this feels hackish from a design perspective.

EDIT: it seems advice functions can be used for this purpose. Is it a sound approach, design-wise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what `(cl-call-next-method)` is for. I am not sure if I am doing things the EIEIO way, because I am following the 'suggestions' made in [this article](https://nullprogram.com/blog/2018/02/14/) by Chris Wellons.
Anyway, the idea is identical in EIEIO.

Here is the example code:

```lisp
(cl-defgeneric greet (greeter)
  (let ((fn (intern (format "%s-is-open" (type-of greeter)))))
    (unless (funcall fn greeter)
      (error "Not open"))))

(cl-defstruct cow is-open)

(setq closed-cow (make-cow :is-open nil))
(setq open-cow (make-cow :is-open t))

(cl-defmethod greet ((c cow))
  (cl-call-next-method)
  (print "do what you want"))

(greet closed-cow)

(greet open-cow)
```

Its up to you in which method you include the call to next method (i.e. which methods you include in your 'subset of methods').

You can learn these things from reading about CLOS (e.g. in [this book](https://gigamonkeys.com/book/object-reorientation-generic-functions.html) by Peter Seibel).

Comment: Thanks a lot, very appreciated, especially the reference!